# C# DirectoryInfo GetFiles returns empty array

Tags: c#

I am trying to read a file from directory with c# DirectoryInfo.getFiles but it returns an empty array. Even though there is a file in the folder, it has all the access permissions and there is no exception thrown.
Although, when I try to run the line in "Immediate window" (VS 2010) it gets the file from the directory properly.

I was googling but, so far I found no answer.
Is there something I missed?

The code is pretty simple:

```
         try
        {

            DirectoryInfo pathDir = new DirectoryInfo(this.path);

            FileInfo[] files = pathDir.GetFiles();

            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
                xml.Load(file.fullName);

                // doing something with XML here   
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The following error has occured: " + exc.Message.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Show us the code that you've wrote

Comment: Are you sure you are debugging in the folder you think you are? You can change this by right-clicking on the C# project, and going to `Properties`. Take a look at the `Debugging` tab.

Comment: Clearly there's something wrong with `this.path`.  The standard mistake is using a relative path instead of an absolute one.  Like `bar` instead of `c:\foo\bar`.  Which makes your code critically depend on Environment.CurrentDirectory

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The path is the same.

Comment: are you getting any exceptions? As @HansPassant stated - there most likely is a problem with your "this.path" variable value.

Comment: The path is ok. I've tried to do the same in a standalone Console Application and it works. This code is a part of a bigger application with a few Threads.

Comment: I am not getting exceptions at all, unfortunately.

Comment: Convince us (and yourself) with a `Console.WriteLine(this.path)`, and compare carefully with a working situation (Immediate window).

Comment: Did you ever find the solution? I am having the same issue.